# Ignore rake task in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler

I have a rake task to populate my db which depends on faker, so at the top there's:

`require 'faker'`

The problem is I don't install faker in production so all rake commands (like `db:migrate`) fail on that require line, saying faker is missing.

Obviously I could install faker in production to get around this, but I don't need it there.  So what's the *right* solution -- can I somehow ignore certain rake tasks in production?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the require statement into the task which actually needs it.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could just do `require 'faker' unless RAILS_ENV='production'`

Comment: That's not a clean solution because what happens if you decide you need that task in `staging`? In this case you can detach the task from the environment, just move the require within the task that needs it.